# GlassFish Metro: Dependency injection in JAX-WS

Tags: dependency-injection, glassfish, osgi, jax-ws, cdi

I require a stateful Web Service and I got it working so far using `@HttpSessionScope`. The service runs in a Servlet provided by the OSGi HttpService. This servlet is created by some Builder service in my OSGi environment. This builder has some services that need to be injected into my Web Service when it gets instantiated. I know that we have the `@Inject` and the `@Resource` annotations for this purpose, but I cannot find a way to add my external object to Glassfish Metro so that those objects get injected into my services.

Have a look to this example:

```
@HttpSessionScope
@WebService
public class AImpl implements A {

    @Inject
    private ADelegated delegated;

        ...
}
```

How can I declare an object of `ADelegated` to be injected into this Web Service? Is there some sort of ResourceInjector in Glassfish Metro that allows me to register an object for injection?

Comment: What is `@HttpSessionScope` in this scenario? Some custom scope of yours?

Comment: No. `@HttpSessionScope` comes from Metro  `com.sun.xml.ws.developer.servlet.HttpSessionScope`.  It means that the JAX-WS RI runtime (Glassfish Metro) will instanciate a new instance of the service class for each `HttpSession`.